# WSO2: What are the differences between some of WSO2's repositories?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-appm

I have been using WSO2 API Manager for a year, and now I want to develop both the UI and analytics aspects in some way and extend a billing engine for it. However, I have some marked questions, and WSO2's company seems unclear about them.

What are the differences between these repositories?

- https://github.com/wso2/product-apim
- https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt
- https://github.com/wso2/apim-apps
- https://github.com/wso2/apim-analytics-publisher
- https://github.com/wso2/carbon-analytics-common
- https://github.com/wso2/carbon-commons

Which one should I develop to get the final product, like WSO2 AM 4.1.0? If I want to use my own database for analytics, which one should I extend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to customize and build the API Manager yourself, use the below repositories:

1. github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt - this is the very first repository you need to build
2. github.com/wso2/product-apim - this is the next repository you need to build.

Both the above repositories contain the source code required to run the API Manager product. The source code includes Publisher, DevPortal, Key Manager, Gateway and Traffic Manager. Under Apache 2.0 license, you are free to make any customizations to the source and build it yourself.

For more information about WSO2 GitHub repositories, please check:
http://wso2.github.io/github-repositories.html

And if you want to publish Analytics data to your own Data Storage, please follow this:

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/api-analytics/samples/publishing-analytics-events-to-external-systems/ - this showcases how you can publish Analytics data to an external system using ELK as an example.